# Como borrar un archivo de una ruta especifica en C++

Tags: c++11, codeblocks

Estoy trabajando en Windows y quiero saber como borrar un archivo con un ruta como por ejemplo :

```
C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\texto.txt
```

He tratado de eliminarlo de la siguiete forma

```
remove(C:\Users\Mario\Desktop\texto.txt)
```

Pero me marca error

¿Como le puedo hacer?

Comment: Marco, cuando preguntes es importante especificar el error, en base a esto los desarrolladores te responderán adecuadamente, revisa por favor [ask], saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para establecer la ruta del archivo a remover debes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
remove("C:\\Users\\Mario\\Desktop\\texto.txt")
```

recuerda que el parámetro es una cadena que indica la ruta del archivo a ser eliminado, revisa la documentación de [**remove()**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) .

Puedes realizar una comprobación para imprimir si se elimino con exito o no el archivo.

```
 if(remove("C:\\Users\\Mario\\Desktop\\texto.txt") != 0 )
    perror("Error al borrar archivo!.");
  else
    puts("El archivo se borro con exito!");
  return 0;
```